# $ a^{n}+b^{n} $ prime. How to show that n is a power of two?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

Let $ a,b \in  \mathbb{N} \setminus \{0,1\}$ and  $n \in \mathbb{N^{\ast }}. $
Let $a^{n}+b^{n} $ prime. How to show that n is a power of two ? I know it works if we suppose that $n=2k(2p+1)$ and then show that it implies $ a^{n}+b^{n} = 0 $ but can't do it.

Sorry, I have a little bit of trouble with LaTex too.

Comment: Hint:  if $n=2^km$ where $m$ is odd then $a^n+b^n$ is divisible by $a^{2^k}+b^{2^k}$.  Of course you have to handle the case where the quotient is $1$, as in $2=1^3+1^3$.

Answer (score 2):

Try to show the following:

Let $n=l2^k$, where $l$ is co prime to $2$ (in other words, it's odd). Then, it is infact true that $a^n+b^n$ is a multiple of $a^{2^k} + b^{2^k}$.

If you can't then look at this box:

> Let $d = a^{2^k}$ and $e=b^{2^k}$, then this is basically saying that $d^l + e^l$ is a multiple of $d+e$ whenever $l$ is odd.
>   Which is true, since $\dfrac{d^l+e^l}{d+e} = \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{l-1} (-1)^ka^kb^{l-1-k}$. Put back $d$ and $e$ in terms of $a$ and $b$ to get the proof.

Therefore, unless $l=1$, the expression $a^n+b^n$ always has a non-trivial factor. Infact, we can even  figure out what it is from the above formula.

For example, $7^6+2^6 = 117713 = 53 \times 2221$, and $53 = 7^2+2^2$.

This proves your statement.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** If $n=(2k+1)m$ with $k\geq 1$ odd then 
$$a^n+b^n=(a^m)^{2k+1}+(b^m)^{2k+1}=(a^m+b^m)(a^{2km}-a^{(2k-1)m}b^m+...+b^{2km})$$